# 'Allowance to cross a road' expression

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I'm confused how to use the word [allowance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/allowance)

The word 'allowance' mostly related to some moneywise issues and that is why I'm not sure that the word 'allowance' fits the occasion and 'permission', 'opportunity' as well

---

Question:

> What is the right way to say *'I stood behind the traffic light and waited for **allowance to cross the road**'*

Comment: Maybe "I stood behind the traffic light and waited until it was OK to cross the road". *OK* meaning when it was safe and legal to do so.

Comment: Where did you find that sentence? It doesn't strike me as idiomatic. It's certainly not anything a native speaker of AmE would say, when speaking naturally.  **permission**, yes, **allowance** no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time *allowance* would not refer to money is with the idiomatic expression *make allowance for X*, meaning to include X in your plans, or to adjust for some factor X.

> The engineers **made allowances for** the loose soil when designing the bridge.
>
> We have to **make allowances for** his lack of experience.

With your example you would instead use the common verb "to allow"; however in this case this would ordinarily imply some *person* who is granting you permission (not a traffic light):

> I stood at the crossing and waited until the policeman **allowed** me to cross.
>
> I stood at the crossing and waited until I **was allowed** to cross.

If you are just waiting on the light to change, you would instead say:

> I stood at the crossing and waited until I **could/was able to** cross.

or simply:

> I stood at the crossing and waited for the light to change.